# Kies is not working after flashing cyanogenmod on my Samsung Android phone

Tags: custom-roms, rom-flashing, samsung-kies

I have flashed my samsung android phone(GT-I5510) to CM7 and everything is fine with it exept that kies has stopped working with it..i.e when I connect my phone to laptop, it doesn't show the option for kies mode.
Please help me with how to enable it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Samsung's Kies software only works with Samsung phones running official Samsung ROMs.

The only way to get Kies working with your phone would be to put an official Samsung released OS version onto it again.